# Move Network Code Out Of Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning iOS development and am finding, when creating my View Controllers, code for things such as networking and such can cause my controller to become huge.

Coming from a web development background, I have always tried to keep my view related code separate from my api related code.

How can I achieve this approach Swift 4?

Is it literally just a case of creating a class called for example, **NetworkService**, keep all API related code in there and referencing it as and when needed?

Are there any good example of this approach? I do not want to create a class full of URLSessions for specific endpoints, so feel like the best approach is something more generic I can pass additional values in to.

Additionally, say for example I have a profile view, when I present that controller, should that controller be requesting the profile data, either via a service or controller networking logic, or should I be populating some form of user object and passing that value into the controller?

Comment: For the record, I felt I should vote to close this because it's too broad and invites options. I also upvoted the accepted answer - it's a more correct way to work with things than the answer suggesting creating an extension to either a specific view controller or `UIViewController`. The comment by @SeanRobinson159 on the answer says it best - while there may be 50 ways to structure your app, 50% of them aren't worth anything - even to you. And while 50% of the remaining *could* work, I'll bet that 10% of them are ones that will be easy to maintain for both you and your peers. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just making a custom class and moving all the networking code there is also an option, but there are several different architectures you can use on iOS. I definitely recommend you to take a look at [this blog entry](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52), specifically take a look into using MVVM or VIPER architectures.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. It is a great answer to the question. It seems like many people do not understand proper app architecture, and app code becomes a huge mess that is difficult for anyone to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an NetworkService.swift file and then extend the specific ViewController you would like to add code to.

So for example, let's say I have a ViewController.swift (with all the main view related code), and then I have another file called NetworkService.swift

In it I could do something like this:

```
extension ViewController {
    func isConnected() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

and then you will be able to call this function from your ViewController file but extensions are not allowed to hold variables. All variables must be declared in the ViewController.swift file

If you want to be able to call the methods from all ViewControllers in your Xcode project, then you should do something like this:

```
extension UIViewController { //changed ViewController to UIViewController
    func isConnected() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You *could* do this, but if you wish to call any methods in this extension from a different view controller, you're duplicating code in an extension to that second controller.

Comment: Then you should extend UIViewController where code will be accessible from all ViewControllers and you will not be duplicating code. I just gave an example to the question he asked.

Comment: Actually, we need to agree to disagree. Yes, extending `UIViewController` will definitely work, but now you are extending a controller where - IMHO - a class works much better. Extending `UIViewController` (1) opens up "network services" to *every* controller whether they want it or not, and (2) doesn't expose it to anything other than `UIViewController`.

Comment: Last comment, I promise. :-)  I never considered downvoting your answer because it's *not* incorrect. It *will* work. But hopefully in comments here and in the OP I explained the price anyone pays by using something more "Swift" specific (a poorly placed extension) when something more OOP specific (a class) works better (at least IMO). *"I just gave an example to the question he asked."* And giving a "specific" example to a "too broad" question can lead to some poorly designed architecture. I was only trying to point out some drawbacks. Again, peace!

Comment: Yeah I get your point but his question was way to broad to really know what he wants. Thanks for your feedback, though!